# pdflatex: conflict between pdfcomment and soul

Tags: hyperref, highlighting, soul, pdfcomment

Here's the MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{pdfcomment}

\begin{document}

\section*{\hl{Fine}}

\section{\hl{Error}}

\end{document}
```

which gives the following error message:

```
! Use of \SOUL@n doesn't match its definition.
\SOUL@ulunderline #1->{\setbox \z@ \hbox {#1}
                                             \dimen@ =\wd \z@ \dimen@i =\SOU...
l.10 \section{\hl{Error}}

?
```

The unnumbered section works fine. Also, when I remove the package `pdfcomment`, everything works.

Answer (score 5):

`pdfcomment` loads `hyperref`, and `hyperref` has no idea what to do with `\hl` in the bookmarks and then errors. Use e.g. `\texorpdfstring` to provide an alternate text for the bookmarks:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{soul}

\usepackage{hyperref}


\begin{document}

\section*{\hl{Fine}}

%\section{\hl{Error}}

\section{\texorpdfstring{\hl{Fine}}{Fine}}

\end{document}
```

As an alternative you can make `\hl` protected

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\AtBeginDocument{\robustify\hl}
```

Then `hyperref` will drop the command at the cost of a warning:

```
Package hyperref Warning: Token not allowed in a PDF string (Unicode):
(hyperref)                removing `\hl' on input line 74.
```

Answer (score 5):

The problem is due to the bookmarks. Make `\hl` to just return its argument when making the bookmark.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{pdfcomment}
%\usepackage{hyperref}

\makeatletter
\pdfstringdefDisableCommands{\let\hl\@firstofone}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\section*{\hl{Fine}}

\section{\hl{Fine as well}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

A quick look at `pdfcomment` documentation shows that it loads `soulpos`, which in turns loads `soulutf8`, which is a `soul` replacement. So you should check whether you're still missing some feature with just loading `pdfcomment`.

Answer (score 1):

`pdfcomment` redefines commands in a way that are incompatible with `soul`. If you are able to use `LuaLaTeX`, here's a possible solution (using `lua-ul` instead):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor,luacolor,lua-ul}
\LuaULSetHighLightColor{yellow}
\usepackage{pdfcomment}

\begin{document}

\section*{\highLight{Fine}}
\section{\highLight{Error}}

\end{document}
```

Note how I had to change `\hl` to `\highLight` in the code, as the soul compatibility mode also failed.

Comment: no it has nothing to do with redefinitions of pdfcomment.

Comment: My wording might have been imprecise. There is, at any rate, a conflict over `\hl`.